# Run tests with Multiple Configurations on jest and playwright

Tags: node.js, jestjs, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer, playwright

I am currently attempting to run automation tests with playwright and jest. I am trying to load multiple configurations(browsertype, resolution, device, url) from a csv file and run tests based on each configuration or test case. Does jest and playwright provide me a way to solve this?

Comment: You can load csv by parsing it with a lib or by hand and run tests inside for loops. There's nothing exotic. Since csv file that you use isn't something that goes without saying, you can expect Jest or Playwright to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

One can configure browsers and devices to test on with [jest-playwright-preset](https://github.com/playwright-community/jest-playwright#configuration). The preset will then launch these browsers and devices for tests.